# Bad image DLL when linking using /INTEGRTIYCHECK option

Tags: c, windows, dll, linker, digital-signature

I am trying to create a simple DLL called **lib.dll** that has the /INTEGRITYCHECK option which from i understand that it will check for digital signatures in an exe or DLL.

I signed the lib.dll with a verified certificate and linked lib.dll with a small application to test it.

When i tried to launch this application i get the following error:
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyliF.png)

What might cause this issue to raise although lib.dll is signed?

I have verified the digital certificate using "signtool verify" command and made sure that the signatures are verified

Comment: You've stated a bunch of unverifiable facts but provided very little evidence for anyone to review it or help you.